# Android Not Loading the Correct Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am a newbie to Android. I am using Android Studio to develop a game. I have 3 activities. The first one to load is a main menu.

The Main Menu loads. Then I can click on one of two buttons. One button loads Activity Main, the other loads an activity named Multiple Choice.

Multiple Choice is the problem. When I select it, the Multiple Choice Class file is used, but the Activity Main is displayed for some reason. Here is the code.

Manifiest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxxxx.ultramath" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MultipleChoice"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_multiple_choice" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Menu

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xxxxxxx.ultramath.MainMenu">

    <TextView android:text="@string/app_name" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnTypeAnswers"
        android:id="@+id/btnTypeAnswers"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnMultipleChoice"
        android:id="@+id/btnMultipleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnTypeAnswers"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnTypeAnswers"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnTypeAnswers"
        android:onClick="btnMultipleChoiceonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Menu Class

```html
public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    public void btnMultipleChoiceonClick(View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MultipleChoice.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Multiple Choice Activity

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MultipleChoice"
android:minWidth="30dp"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<TextView android:text="@string/LeftText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Timeleft"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Operator"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Operator" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/OperatorText"
    android:id="@+id/Operator"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Timeleft"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/RightText"
    android:id="@+id/Right"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Timeleft"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Operator"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Operator" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/StartButton"
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="btnStart_Click"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/TimeLeft"
    android:id="@+id/Timeleft"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Correct: 0"
    android:id="@+id/CorrectAnswers"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Timeleft"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LinearContainer"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearContainer"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CorrectAnswers"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CorrectAnswers"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Multiple Choice Class

```html
public class MultipleChoice extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView Left;
    TextView Operator;
    TextView Right;
    TextView GameTimer;
    TextView CorrectAnswers;
    ImageView imageView[] = new ImageView[8];
    int imageViewNumber;

    Button btnStart;

    int intLeft;
    int intOperator;
    int intRight;
    int intCorrectAnswer;

    int intCorrectAnswers;
    String strCorrectAnswer;

    CountDownTimer problemtimer = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            NextProblem();
        }
    };

    CountDownTimer gametimer = new CountDownTimer(60000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            GameTimer.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            problemtimer.cancel();
            gametimer.cancel();
            GameTimer.setText("Time Left: 0");
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SetStartupValues();
    }

    private  void SetStartupValues(){
        Left = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Left);
        Operator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Operator);
        Right = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Right);
        GameTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timeleft);
        CorrectAnswers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CorrectAnswers);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        Left.setText("");
        Operator.setText("");
        Right.setText("");
        GameTimer.setText("Time Left: 60");
        CorrectAnswers.setText("Correct: 0");
        intCorrectAnswers = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void btnStart_Click(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button click
        SetStartupValues();
        NextProblem();
        gametimer.start();
        btnStart.setEnabled(false);
    }


    public void  NextProblem(){
        intLeft = new Random().nextInt(100);
        intRight= new Random().nextInt(100);
        intOperator= new Random().nextInt(3);
        Left.setText(String.valueOf(intLeft));
        Right.setText(String.valueOf(intRight));
        imageViewNumber=0;

        switch(intOperator){
            case 0:
                Operator.setText("+");
                intCorrectAnswer = intLeft + intRight;
                break;
            case 1:
                Operator.setText("-");
                intCorrectAnswer=intLeft-intRight;
                break;
            case 2:
                Operator.setText("X");
                intCorrectAnswer=intLeft*intRight;
                break;
        }
        strCorrectAnswer = String.valueOf(intCorrectAnswer);
        GetNumbers(strCorrectAnswer);
        problemtimer.start();
    }

    private void GetNumbers(String strNumber){
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        int L = strNumber.length();
        String c;
        for (int i = 1;i<L;i++){
            c=strNumber.substring(i,i+1);
            switch (c){
                case "1":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.one);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.two);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.three);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.four);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.five);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "6":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.six);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "7":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seven);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "8":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.eight);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "9":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nine);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                case "0":
                    imageView[imageViewNumber].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zero);
                    ll.addView(imageView[imageViewNumber]);
                    break;
                }

            }


        }
```

I apologize if I posted to much code. I have no idea where the problem may lie.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in the concerned activity is the problem

Comment: what layout are you using for MainActivity?

Comment: Thanks User210504. I see that now. Thanks for pointing that out for me. That happened because I copied and pasted from the Main Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Mention below lines only inside of your main launcher activity tag in mainifest file:

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

because it will fllow the top down approach in manifest file.

Comment: So, should I remove the intent-filter tags from the other activities?

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. So, the first activity to load is the only one that needs those lines. of code.